View Creation Date/Time of a Powershell Variable
I'm trying to figure out a way to view the creation date/time of a variable in Powershell.  For example if I create the variable:
PS C:\> $name = 'alice'
PS C:\> $name
alice

When I look at the available properties I only get:
PS C:\> Get-Variable name | Format-List

Name        : name
Description :
Value       : alice
Visibility  : Public
Module      :
ModuleName  :
Options     : None
Attributes  : {}

Is there another method that would show me the creation date/time of a variable?

I am curios to know the usecase.

There isn't....

@user459872 I'm attempting to create a create a script to that will be run multiple times during the day using the same encrypted password set to a variable.  I want the variable to be independent of script so it doesn't have to keep running.  my thought is to have it be removed at a certain time since i can't find a way to have it be self-destructing (the best option if it were possible).

Short answer: no.
Long answer: no without using workarounds logging the events.
Easiest case scenario would require creating all variables like this:
$ThisIsAVariable = 'But a String' | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Creationtime -Value (Get-date) -PassThru


sirtao's helpful answer addresses your question as asked.
Let me complement it with a solution that addresses your ultimate goal:  self-destruction of a variable based on a timeout:
Assuming you have function Set-ExpiringGlobalVariable defined (see source code below), you could call it as follows:
Set-ExpiringGlobalVariable mySecret someSecret 300

This creates a global $mySecret variable with value 'someSecret', which is automatically removed after 300 seconds == 5 minutes (at the earliest - depends on when the engine becomes idle again).
If you globally set $VerbosePreference = 'Continue' first, a verbose message will print at the time of removal.
Note:

The solution supports only creating global variables that self-destruct.

It uses Register-EngineEvent with the PowerShell.OnIdle engine event to run code whenever the engine is idle, which notably happens when control is returned to the interactive prompt.

A single event subscriber that handles all self-destructing variables is defined per session, which, due to use of the -SupportEvent switch, is by default hidden from Get-EventSubscriber; add -Force to show it.


A dictionary of self-destructing variable names along with their expiration timestamps is maintained in global helper variable $__segv_Helper, which - due to being declared with the Private option - will not be seen by descendent scopes (such as scripts).



Set-ExpiringGlobalVariable source code:
function Set-ExpiringGlobalVariable {
    param($Name, $Value, $TimeoutSeconds = 300)
    Set-Variable -Scope Global $Name $Value
    $expirationDate = [datetime]::UtcNow.AddSeconds($TimeoutSeconds)
    if (-not ($helperVarObj = Get-Variable -ErrorAction Ignore -Scope Global '__segv_Helper')) {
      Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.OnIdle -SupportEvent -Action {
        if ($dictOfExpiringVariables = Get-Variable -ValueOnly -ErrorAction Ignore -Scope Global '__segv_Helper') {
          $utcNow = [datetime]::UtcNow
          @($dictOfExpiringVariables.GetEnumerator()) | Where-Object Value -le $utcNow | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Verbose "Removing global variable `$$($_.Key); it expired on $($_.Value.ToLocalTime())"
            $dictOfExpiringVariables.Remove($_.Key)
            Remove-Variable -ErrorAction Ignore -Force -Scope Global $_.Key
          }
        }
      }
      $helperVarObj = Set-Variable -PassThru -Scope Global -Option Private, Constant '__segv_Helper' ([ordered] @{})
    }
    $helperVarObj.Value[$Name] = $expirationDate
}


I don't know why you want to know the creation time of a variable. Probably it's not useful enough for PowerShell to track
It's possible to do that indirectly though the history though, because StartExecutionTime and EndExecutionTime are recorded so it's possible to know the duration of each executed command even when you forgot to use Measure-Command
(Get-History | Where-Object {$_.CommandLine -like '$name = *'}).StartExecutionTime

Of course you may need to modify the match string to make it match better, for example $_.CommandLine -match '\b\$name\s*=\s*' but it still won't work for all cases, because it may match a string in the comment part, or inside a string. It may also return incorrect result for complex commands, like
command that takes a long time; $name = 'alice'

